# Using REGEX to parse serialized data

Tags: regex, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've learned the error of serialization... now I have to pay for it. In my DB, I have records where the String attribute looks like this:

`"---\n- '0'\n- Tent\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- Sleeping pad\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n"`

Is there an easy way to parse out ONLY the two items inside? In this case the items are Tent and Sleeping pad, but note that in these long strings, there can be any number of items hidden...

FYI this was Ruby on Rails 4.

Comment: what is your expected output? Input is the string you provided, output is "Tent Sleeping pad" or what?

Comment: Ideally I'd like the output to be `Tent, Sleeping pad, next item, so forth` so I can convert to an array and then can run an enumerable across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry, not to steal anyone's thunder, but I literally don't know RegEx at all, so I wasn't sure where the put the line of code. I ended up using a pure ruby way though, just:

```
long_string = "---\n- '0'\n- Tent\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- Sleeping pad\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n- '0'\n"
new_array = long_string.split("\n- ")
#mimic what the serialization function does, which is splitting up each of the items with the "\n- " thing

new_array.select! { |t| ("A".."Z").include? t[0] }
#select only elements of the newly created array where the first character is a capital letter, since it works out that all my items would start with a capital letter
```

Output in this case would be `=> ["Tent", "Sleeping pad"]`

Answer (score 0):

With this entry, you need the following string to pluck these words

```
(?<=^|\\n-\s)([\p{L} ]+?)(?=\\n)
```

Use this if U havent "lazy".

```
(?<=^|\\n-\s)([a-zA-Z ]+?)(?=\\n)
```

Comment: Hi sorry, how exactly do I use this? once I have `items` as an object? I tried doing `items.split...` but that seemed to require more info. Thanks!

Comment: I dont know about Ruby regex, but perhaps this can help: http://regex101.com/r/rX5jU9/1  Its almost the same as his second regex (except non-capture group added on start with ?:) and it works. Do not forget to do a global match.

Comment: Oh - tested it here as well and my edited regex finds both words http://rubular.com/  (put your string in and my edited regex)

Comment: Thanks for just introducing me to that tool! Will have to play with it